# The application was unable to start correctly 0xc000007b from mysqld.exe

Tags: windows-10, apache-http-server, webserver, windows-server-2008, wamp

I'm trying to install wamp 3.1.9 in windows 10 . I've all the VC packages setup, 2 services are running fine. Mysql is not starting up. 
This is the first time 'm setting up wamp.

This is the error thrown,

The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). from mysqld.exe

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching around, a lot of resources say this is due to mixing 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows and applications, such as [this one](https://www.easeus.com/backup-recovery/this-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly.html):

> Typically you'll see this error when there's a mixing of 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows and applications.

On the Server Fault SE Site, I found [a post](https://serverfault.com/questions/752529/mysqld-exe-crases-on-startup-with-error-0xc000007b) about this error and they said the 32-bit version worked for them.

> I've tried to reinstall it many times with no success. **However**, the 32bit version installs, runs and works normally.

Finally, a [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10493137/6530134) said the following:

> To start, I would suggest to test whether there is a problem between your application and its dependencies using [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

The comments on that post later go on to say that the error code boils down to the message "STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT" (which was also mentioned on the Server Fault post) to which someone replied saying:

> Which is a good indication that the 32-bit app tried to load a 64-bit DLL.

So it seems like one solution is to replace any 64-bit DLLs the application tries loading with 32-bit versions.  Using that Dependency Walker tool could aid you in figuring that out.